# Eclipse on ARM (ubuntu)

Tags: eclipse, ubuntu, arm

I've installed Ubuntu on my tablet (Nvidia Shield Tablet). 
Would it be somehow possible to run Eclipse on this machine?
It has an ARM processor.

uname -a

```
Linux shield 3.10.40-g793214a #9 SMP PREEMPT Tue Jul 21 09:57:49 PDT 2015 armv7l armv7l armv7l GNU/Linux
```

Comment: If you can find linux arm based swt libraries and a ARM jvm. Then it could work ;)

Comment: It's seem that it realy can work. Look here: https://resheim.net/2013/05/running-eclipse-rcp-applications-on.html

Comment: This question is becoming rather critical. I have Ubuntu running on a Tegra K1 and it makes up for quite an able system. Every other software works quite well, but with Eclipse it seems the only option seems to be trying to compile it yourself.